# How can I pass floating point numbers through $a0 in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine

I am writing a MIPS library in which I am planning to pass all the arguments through `$aX` registers and return all the values through `$vX` registers.

I have written the following function:

```
# PrintFloat - prints a float
# arguments:
#   $a0 = arress of the float
# return value:
#   n/a
PrintFloat: 
    move $f12, $a0
    li $v0, 2
    syscall
    # return 
    jr $ra
```

this function is not compiling in MARS.

I have three questions here:

1. Is it not possible to pass floats through `$a` registers at all?
2. Should I design the library to pass the arguments through `$sp` instead (using `$sp` is comparatively messy)?
3. Do I need to create stack frames in every trivial functions like this in order to make it non-leaf safe?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Pass FP args in FP registers like a normal person, instead of forcing caller and callee to copy FP data to/from integer regs.  Or if not in FP regs, then on the stack is maybe better than in integer registers, especially for `double` which would take 2x 32-bit registers if you can't use MIPS64.  Same for returning by value: return in `$f0` or something instead of v0/v1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it not possible to pass floats through $a registers at all?

It is possible. But in MIPS, FP is considered as a coprocessor for historical reasons and you must use specific instruction to copy move data between the processor and a coprocessor : `MFC` (move from coprocessor) and `MTC` (move to coprocessor). FP unit is coprocessor 1 and the corresponding instructions are `mfc1` and `mtc1`.

```
mfc1 rt, fs  # copy data from fp register fs to gp register rt
```

Similarly to copy to a fp register, use `mtc1`

```
mtc1 rs, ft  # copy data from gp register rs to fp register ft
```

So you just have to use

```
mfc1 $a0, $f12
```

to put $f12 in $a0.

> Should I design the library to pass the arguments through $sp instead (using $sp is comparatively messy)?

No, it is useless, unless you have a large number of arguments.

> Do I need to create stack frames in every trivial functions like this in order to make it non-leaf safe?

No. But stack frames are of course required if you need to save registers in the caller or the callee. And to save $ra if your function calls another function.

Comment: Passing FP args on the stack might be better than in integer registers, especially for `double` on 32-bit MIPS.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see why. The number of assembly instructions is identical `mfc1.d` vs `l.d`, if function is terminal you don't have to set up a stack frame, you gain four memory accesses and sticking to the calling conventions is always better for code reuse.

Comment: `mfc1.d` is a pseudo-instruction that copies each 32-bit integer register separately.  `ldc1` is a 64-bit load into a pair of `$f` registers, which the HW already supports writing as a combined 64-bit entity for double-precision ALU instructions.  (Or is that only supported on 64-bit MIPS?  MARS supports it, and it only emulates a 32-bit MIPS.)